# Does logback support separate logging for JPMS layers/module?

Tags: java, logback, java-9, java-module

I have an application that uses JPMS layers and modules. Is it possible to log messages for every layer/module in separate file using logback? If yes, then how?

Comment: should't this be possible with different appenders in `logback.xml`?

Comment: @Eugene I don't know, that's why I am asking. I didn't find the solution, did you?

Comment: I don't have such a need or a problem, to be honest. But you could read appenders in logback and how they are created and how you could point some packages to some appenders, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems to be impossible this moment I opened an issue here: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1514